# How do I install Parallels Tools via the command line?

Tags: 10.10, server, command-line, virtualization, parallels

I have Ubuntu Server 10.10 running on Parallels 6 (latest update from yesterday) on my iMac. I click on the Install Parallels Tools in the Parallels Desktop Menu, but do not see where what I think should be the file prl-tools-lin.iso is placed.

Don't understand whether the warning that I may have to do `mount -o exec` applies to me or not. Think I might be able to mount and run the .iso file, if I can locate it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

I have solved this issue with Ubuntu Server 18.04 as follows:

1) Click "Update Parallels tools" (upper right corner of the parallels virtual machine window)

2) Log in and then give the commands:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/cdrom /media/cdrom
$ cd /media/cdrom
$ sudo ./install
```

If, when mounting the CD-ROM, you get the error:

`mount: /media/cdrom: unknown filesystem type 'iso9660'`

you can fix this using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: This was the one that worked for me, except I used sudo mount /dev/cdrom /cdrom

Comment: I had to run `sudo mkdir /media/cdrom` before `sudo mount` (because otherwise it would say: `mount: mount point /media/cdrom does not exist`), but aside from that, everything here worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

With Parallels 10.1.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 using the menu entry `Actions -> Install parallels tools...` did not mount the installer in /media/parallels. Trying `sudo updatedb; locate prl-tools-lin.iso` also returned an empty result.

The solution is to `cd /usr/lib/parallels-tools` then `sudo ./install`, which will execute the text installer. Incidentally `sudo ./install-gui` (from the same directory) will execute the GUI installer (requires X server).

Answer (score 5):

To find a file on your compute you can use the built in index, from a command line:

`sudo updatedb; locate prl-tools-lin.iso`

But really to answer this question we need to go to [the guides](http://forum.parallels.com/pda/index.php/t-13553.html):

```
Select Actions -> Install parallels tools...
In a terminal, enter:
cd /media/Parallels\ Tools/
sudo sh parallels-tools.run
```

If this fails to work then you can get the iso file and mount it manually like so:

sudo mount -o loop /path/to/prl-tools-lin.iso /mnt

Don't forget to unmount it when you're finished:

sudo umount /mnt

Comment: I've seen the same thing in Ubuntu, 10.04, 10.10 and 11.04. The image does not mount when selecting *Install Parallels Tools*. I have to locate the `prl-tools-lin.iso` file on my machine, then execute sudo mount -o loop /path/to/prl-tools-lin.iso /media/cdrom

Comment: A note for newer versions of Ubuntu & Parallels: You can specify the `prl-tools-lin.iso` in the CD-ROM at the bottom of the window (set the disk image you want in the preferences), and the path is `/media/<USERNAME>/Parallels\ Tools/` and the executable you want now is called `install`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Parallels 6+ instead of typing: "sudo sh parallels-tools.run" you will probably need to type "sudo sh install" without the quotation marks.

Comment: From what directory?